# make text in the middle of the div or image

Tags: html, css

I have this html

```
<div class="vmpLogoClass">
     <span style="margin-top:10px; vertical-align:middle">Powred by:</span>
     <img alt="vmplogo" src="images/inconcert_logo.png" style="float:right;" />
</div>
```

and this is the **css:**

```
.vmpLogoClass {
    width:29%;
    float:right;
    text-align:right;
}
```

This is the result:
[image]

I need the text to be in the center. I mean not at the top of the image.

I tried giving margin-top but it seems that the margion-top is not affected anything.

Comment: Try using, `line-height: (the height of the image) px;`

Comment: @CTravel that works. thanks. Write an answer please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using, `line-height: (the height of the image) px;`

In my case with the same logo it should be:
**Css:**

```
span { line-height:104px;}
```

Check the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vvw5s/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

**you can try to this**

```
.vmpLogoClass {
float:right;
}
.vmpLogoClass span, .vmpLogoClass img{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SEQ8s/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

First, remove `Class` from your class name and strip the style tags out of the HMTL markup.

```
<div class="vmpLogo">
     <span>Powered by:</span>
     <img alt="vmplogo" src="http://www.crossfone.com.ar/imgs/logo_inconcert.jpg" />
</div>


.vmpLogo {
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
}

.vmpLogo span {
    display: block;
}

.vmpLogo img {
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J7wUs/

[image]

Comment: Oops, I misread that you wanted text to be left of the image. My mistake.

Comment: You could switch up your markup so that you're using an inline list (e.g. `<ul>`) and put top padding on the content in the first element.